# How to use a QTCPServer in multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, qt, thread-safety, qtcpserver

I am trying to write a webserver that processes requests from multiple clients simultaneously. The way it is designed, only one request can be processed at a time.

What I need is a way to call `nextPendingConnection()` and then dispatch the connection to a separate thread for processing.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Something that might be of interest is that you do not necessarily need threads as you can use the Qt event system. Take a look at [Threads Events QObjects](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sample here should explain it http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html